# Jersey: list of JSON objects

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I am trying to retrieve in my Jersey implementation resource class post collection of objects like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String sendEmails(ArrayList<AnyEmail> email) {
    //emailManager.sendEmail(email);
    return "success";
}
```

I have the `@XmlRootElement` above `AnyEmail.

However when I post like this with REST client tool:

```
 emails : [
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"},
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"}
      ]
```

I get:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.zzScanError(JsonLexer.java:491)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.yylex(JsonLexer.java:736)
```

**EDITED**
Now I tried:

```
 "emails" : [
           {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"},
           {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"}
          ]
```

and I get:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/API] threw exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:324)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.valueRead(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.readNext(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:330)
```

Comment: I believe you should send JSON array instead of JSON object. Try sending just `[{...},{...}]` segment as request entity.

Comment: When I do it I get: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"body"). Expected elements are <{}anyEmail>]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what should work:

```
{
"anyEmail" : [
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"},
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"}
       ]
}
```

Also, you may want to use the POJO approach, which is the preferred one for JSON - see here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html

The JSON support based on JAXB has various issues with some edge cases, since there isn't a 1:1 mapping between XML (JAXB as designed for) and JSON.

Comment: This is consumable format in case of mapped JSON notation, right? If natural is used, just passing an JSON array should work?

Answer (score 7):

Why you don't use a simple Java array???

```
[
   {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"},
   {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"}
]
```

And then the following method:

```
@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String sendEmails(AnyEmail[] emails) {
    //emailManager.sendEmail(emails);
    return "success";
}
```

That should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

I'm neither a Jersey nor Json expert, but did you try using a full JSON object, ie :

```
{
"emails" : [
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"},
       {"body": "Testing the web service", "header": "Hi", "footer": "<br/>test"}
      ]
}
```

(added braces, and quotes to emails).

Comment: This sounds much better. "Bad Request" is a expectable return code. I'd dig into typing here, eg AnyEmail is mappable onto {"body": "", "header": "", "footer": ""} ? No additional idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to wrap the AnyEmail class.

This can help you: https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/missing_brackets_at_json_one

Answer (score 0):

// Client

```
package com.project.rest.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Client {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String lang;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Client(Long id, String email, String lang) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.lang = lang;
    }

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
    return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLang() {
    return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Client [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", lang=" + lang + "]";
    }

}
```

//ClientService

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;

@Path("/client")
public class ClientService {

    @POST
    @Path("/sendList")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJSONList(List<Client> clientList) {

        String output = "consumeJSONList Client : " + clientList.toString() + "\n\n";

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

//JerseyClient

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;
import com.project.rest.model.Device;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

public class JerseyClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

    List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
    clientList.add(new Client(1L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(2L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(3L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client c = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(clientConfig);

    WebResource webResource = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/project_rest/rest/client/sendList");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, clientList);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed sendClientList: HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println("sendClientList... Server response .... \n");
    System.out.println(output);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
}
}
```

//POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.10-b01</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jersey 1.17 and can receive list of JSON objects with the following signature and cast them into list of my POJO Objects with Google's gson library, without any issue. Using wrapper to wrap list of POJO objects, is certainly un-natural and not favourable.

```
   @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({"application/x-javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response doSomething(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, JSONArray listOfJSONObjects) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List < MYPOJOClass > myPojoObjectList = gson.fromJson(listOfJSONObjects.toString(), new TypeToken < List < MYPOJOClass >> () {}.getType());
```