# How to send POST request with Many-to-many relationship in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add a order with equipment list, here's my entities:

the order entity

```
 @Entity @Table(name = "orders") public class Order extends Ticket{
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrderEquipment> orderEquipments = new HashSet<>();}
```

the equipment entity

```
 @Entity @Table(name = "equipments") public class Equipment extends DateAudit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 30)
private String name;


@NotNull
private Long nbr_piece ;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<OrderEquipment> orderEquipments = new HashSet<>();}
```

and the order_equipment entity

```
@Entity @Table(name = "order_equipment") public class OrderEquipment extends DateAudit { @Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Order order;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id")
private Equipment equipment;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "quantity")
private Long quantity;}
```

here is the add function in the orderController

```
 @PostMapping("/orders")
public Order createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody Order Order){
 Order.setObservateurEmail(Order.getObservateurEmail());
 Order.setObject(Order.getObject());
 Order.setDescription(Order.getDescription());      
 return orderRepository.save(Order);          
}
```

Comment: Please share what is the expected output and what error are you facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a mistakes there, lemme try to help you. Since you issue is not clear, please lemme know if it does/does not work:

You have two bidirectional mappings there:

- Order (with ALL cascade) <-> OrderEquipment
- Equipment (with ALL cascade) <-> OrderEquipment

You are using @JoinColumn for both of them, even though they are bidirectional. Please take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby). You should always use the `mappedBy` attribute when defining bidirectional relationships.

Now, you are receiving an Order object from a POST request, making changes to 3 attributes and then saving it. Since the mapping between the `Order` and `OrderEquipment` have the `CascadeType.ALL` attribute, any save on the Order object will save all OrderEquipment children associated. If the Order object you are receiving already have OrderEquipment children, your method will also save/update them.

Your POST mapping looks good to me, just take care with your table relationship definitions.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648827/jersey-list-of-json-objects) to check how a lits of entities should be formatted on a JSON POST.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the mapping, but in my post request on postman i didn't know how to add a list of orderEquipment {"observateurEmail" :"test@gmail.com","object" :"order","description":"desc", ....} to save it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check the extra link I have added to see how a list of entities is formatted on a JSON POST.

Comment: That's not really answer my question, i need to send list of orderEquipment which contains an equipment , a quantity and an order who am already creating it in same moment.

Comment: Wait a minute... The OrderEquipment object is a son of two fathers... You can only assign one father for it at a time via JSON POST. If you wanna establish all relationships mapped there, you should post a JSON with an Order mapping a list of OrderEquipment, and another post with an Equipment mapping a list of OrderEquipment.

Comment: Well thank you , i finally try to save the order first then the orderEquipment object, that's work good ...